# Unhandled promise rejection nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to use [openweather-apis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openweather-apis) to connect to a dialogflow agent. I am new to promises and I keep getting the warning `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and I'm not sure on how to fix this.

Currently I have 2 files weather.js, which makes the api call

```
const api = require("openweather-apis")

api.setAPPID(process.env.API_KEY)
api.setUnits("metric")

module.exports = {
  setCity: function(city) {
     api.setCity(city)
  },

 getWeather: function() {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         api.getTemperature(function(err, temp) {
             if (err) reject(err)
             resolve(temp)
         })
     })
  }
}
```

And I make use of weatherinCity.js, which retrieves the city from the agent, calls the calling function and then sends a response to the user.

```
const weather = require("../../weather")


module.exports = {
 fulfillment: function(agent) {
     const city = agent.parameters.geo_city
     weather.setCity(city)
     weather.getWeather().then(function(temp) {
         agent.add(
             "It is ${temp} degrees Celcius in ${city}"
         )
     }).catch(() => {
         console.error("Something went wrong")
     })
 }
}
```

full error message:

```
(node:2896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No responses defined for platform: DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE
at V2Agent.sendResponses_ (C:\Users\Coen\Desktop\ciphix-ca-case\node_modules\dialogflow-fulfillment\src\v2-agent.js:243:13)
at WebhookClient.send_ (C:\Users\Coen\Desktop\ciphix-ca-case\node_modules\dialogflow-fulfillment\src\dialogflow-fulfillment.js:505:17)
at C:\Users\Coen\Desktop\ciphix-ca-case\node_modules\dialogflow-fulfillment\src\dialogflow-fulfillment.js:316:38
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async 
function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not 
handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled 
promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see 
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). 
(rejection id: 1)
(node:2896) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections 
are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled 
will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: can you show the full message of the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`?

Comment: @alramdein I edited the post with the full error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indeed happened because this code fails to handle the Promise Rejection. While I'm not sure which Promise Rejection that failed to handle, but based on [this](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/22) and [this](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/issues/203) GitHub discussions. It seems you need to `return` the `agent.add()` function.

I recommend trying `async-await` style with the consequence that you have to add a `try catch block`

```
module.exports = {
    fulfillment: async function(agent) {
        try {
            const city = agent.parameters.geo_city
            weather.setCity(city)
            let temp = await weather.getWeather()
            agent.add(
                "It is ${temp} degrees Celcius in ${city}"
            )
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Something went wrong")
            console.error(err)
        }
   }
}
```

Every error that is thrown on the `try block` should be caught in a `catch block`. Don't forget to add `async` before the `function`.

Comment: This almost fixed it for me! The only change I had to make was to store the return value of ```await weather.getWeather()``` in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

it will not solve your problem but generally speaking, i would add "return" after if(err). because otherwise the call to resolve would be done. in your particular case it will do no harm, as because of the nature of promises it will be ignored. but if you had written anything between reject and resolve it would have been executed.

```
// best practice
if (err) return reject(err)
```

for your problem, i've just tried this fast test to convice myself that even throws are catched by .catch() so i think you must be running a bad/old nodejs version, or the code you provided is not complete, and the failure is elsewere. I dont see any line pointing to your own code in the log O_o (only node_modules).

which nodejs version is it ?

```
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    throw new Error('test');
    resolve('ok')
})

p.then(console.log).catch(function(err) {
    console.error('err', err)
});
```

Comment: I'm using node v14.16.0